# jQuery change on click even to on load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following code which I've put together, and I need to change it from the onclick event to onload, so it loads the modal window automatically when the page is loaded. However, for the life of me I can't work out how do it, i've tried many a permutation it just doesn't seem to work!

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); 
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); 
        var query = popURL.split('?');
        var dim = query[1].split('&');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; 

        $('#' + popID)
            .fadeIn()
            .css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) })
            .prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

        $('#' + popID).css({
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); 
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); 

        return false;
    });

    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { 
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove(); 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This loads it at the moment:

```
<a href="#?w=200" rel="popup_name" class="poplight">Popup</a>
```

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: Which popup plugin are you using? If you check through it's documentation there is likely to be a `trigger` function or some such, which allows you to programmatically show a modal window through code without needing user interaction.

Comment: Theres no plugin, it's all in the code above :-)

Comment: I've just googled the plugin name and found it. On the documentation there is a guide on setting up the popup on load: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/#comment-8729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the [documentation for the plugin](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/#comment-8729) you can move the logic for the popup into it's own function (called `popOpen()` in the example) and call that on load like this:

```
$('a.poplight[href=#?w=200]').popOpen();
```

Comment: Thanks for that matey, I didn't get it from there so didn't even think to google it! Life saver

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').trigger("click");
```

Or:

```
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click();
```

These should be in your DOM Ready.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $this = $('a.poplight[href^=#]');
    var popID = $this.attr('rel'); 
....
```